# How to deliver exception in zip() function to subscriber

Tags: java, android, rx-java, rx-android

I'm using RxJava 1.x on Android at language level 1.7 (so no lambda's please). I'm trying to combine 4 streams using the `zip()` operator. However, the `Func4` implementation I use may run into `IOException`s which need to be dealt with somehow. However, the `Func4#call()` signature doesn't allow throwing exceptions. So I'm wondering how to deal with these. Ideally the exceptions would be delivered to the `onError()` method of the `Subscriber` which will subscribe to the `Observable` resulting from the `zip()` operation.

Some sample code:

```
public Observable<R> combine(Observable<A> observable1, Observable<B> observable2, Observable<C> observable3, Observable<D> observable4) {
    return Observable<R>.zip(observable1, observable2, observable3, observable4, new Func4<A, B, C, D, R> {
    public R call(A a, B b, C c, D d) {
        // some code which may throw IOExceptions
    }});
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just throw an exception that extends `RuntimeException` when your `IOException` occurs. It will be delivered to the `onError` callback of the `Subscriber`.

Comment: Also note that you can wrap your ioexception in a runtimeexception with the IOE as cause, so that you can retrieve the actual exception in the onError.

Comment: Thanks for the speedy response!

Answer (score 3):

You could also use:

```
Exceptions.propagate(throwable)
```

It will wrap your Throwable into RuntimeException and delivered onError channel.